# Placing a blurred circle on a jpeg in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

If I am going to generate a circle to be placed on a JPEG image using the `insertShape` function, like so:

```
img = imread('someImage.jpg');
img = insertShape(img, 'FilledCircle', [150 280 35], ...
    'LineWidth',5, 'Color','blue');
imshow(img)
```

Is there a way for me to apply something like a Gaussian blue to the circle, but not to the entire JPEG image?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this:

```
img = imread('someImage.jpg');
shape = insertShape(zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2)), 'FilledCircle',
                    [150 280 35], 'LineWidth',5, 'Color',1);
shape = imgaussfilt(shape);
img(:,:,1) = img(:,:,1) .* (1-shape); % + 0 * shape;
img(:,:,2) = img(:,:,2) .* (1-shape); % + 0 * shape;
img(:,:,3) = img(:,:,3) .* (1-shape) + 255 * shape;
imshow(img)
```

I'm drawing the shape on a blank (grey-scale) image, apply a Gaussian filter to that, then insert it with the right weights into each channel.

I'm not sure if the `'Color',1` argument works, the intention there is to draw the shape with a value of 1 in the grey-value image, so that it can be used as a weight (I don't have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, so cannot test this).